# Beginner Java Challenges

Tags: java

Is there any site where I can go that has a fairly large list of challenges for the different levels of coders? I'm hoping for a huge list of each experience level but am looking for ones for beginners challenges right now.

Comment: Try to provide answers on SO, that's a challenge!

Comment: how about a site or forum dedicated to challenges.

Answer (score 7):

[codingbat.com](http://codingbat.com/) is one of my personal favorites.

Answer (score 2):

I would check out [Top Coder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=ProblemArchive).  You can go through all the archives of problems from competitions in the past and practice them.  They are all separated into 3 levels of difficulty from fairly straightforward to rather difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I program in Python, this can work for you, too. Look online for Python programs, and just try to do the same thing in Java. This got me pretty far in the beginning, trying to learn how to do simple guessing games and card games.